# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. following error coming when i run this code this code i used for check gridview check box

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)GridView1.FindControl("chkid");

        if (ch.Checked)
        {
            Response.Write("ch= true");
            Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows.ToString();
        }
        else
            Response.Write("ch= false");
    }                 
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Correct This Line.

```
CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a null check before using checkbox

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)GridView1.FindControl("chkid");

        if (ch != null)
        {
            if (ch.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write("ch= true");
                Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows.ToString();
            }
            else
                Response.Write("ch= false");
        }
    }                 
 }
```